# Is there any info table/matrix which shows the attributes of char, varchar, text, real, double, float, binary, set, int, integer, longtext?

Tags: mysql, database, types, char

Is there any info table/matrix which shows the attributes of char, varchar, text, real, double, float, binary, set, int, integer, longtext, blob, numeric, datatime, varbinary?

Edit: yes, like online documentation.

Comment: Like the online documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file